# SuiteTalk Netsuite Integration - use SOAP or REST?

Tags: netsuite, suitetalk, invoice-ninja

I am writing an application that reads customer and invoice data for an account on Netsuite. For integration, Netsuite provides two types of APIs, SOAP and REST. The SOAP is an older one and sounds reliable. There is even a Java SDK on the SOAP API. But the REST API is still in beta. Certain endpoints of importance to me, like /account, /customer etc are all in beta. Is it good to go with the REST API or with SOAP?

Answer (score 2):

By far, use the SOAP api.  The REST api lacks a lot of features, like multiple-shipping routes for sales orders and is generally speaking more consistent and more reliable than the REST api.  Based on our experience in working with the REST api and entering in support tickets about the REST api, it's our opinion that netsuite isn't serious about the REST api or feature parity with the soap api.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @2ps that SOAP is better.  In addition to lack of features, OAuth authentication for REST has never worked for me, though it works fine for SOAP.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30433346)